# Node.js rss memory leak

Tags: node.js, typescript

It seems as if I have a memory leak in my Node.js application. It's a server that fetches metadata and thumbnail images from external servers for URLs that our end users post.

This isn't a type of leak I've seen before. Memory leaks I've worked on before were always heap based. This one seems to be outside the heap in rss memory.

The server is pretty busy, around 60 - 100 requests per second. It's running Node version: 18.16.1 in a Docker container in a Kubernetes environment (base image node:18.16). The container is running Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm).

I did some logging using `process.memoryUsage()` and got these results from one of the containers:

```
2024-02-08T21:28:23.009 GMT --- 153mb heap used, 181mb heap total, 392mb rss
2024-02-08T23:28:26.556 GMT --- 153mb heap used, 183mb heap total, 386mb rss
2024-02-09T01:28:49.670 GMT --- 152mb heap used, 199mb heap total, 412mb rss
2024-02-09T03:28:23.041 GMT --- 171mb heap used, 200mb heap total, 425mb rss
2024-02-09T06:28:24.343 GMT --- 157mb heap used, 187mb heap total, 430mb rss
2024-02-09T08:28:32.185 GMT --- 167mb heap used, 178mb heap total, 421mb rss
2024-02-09T10:28:23.665 GMT --- 161mb heap used, 182mb heap total, 425mb rss
2024-02-09T12:28:23.187 GMT --- 164mb heap used, 189mb heap total, 429mb rss
2024-02-09T13:25:22.164 GMT --- 167mb heap used, 223mb heap total, 467mb rss
```

Heap usage seems OK, but total heap allocated seems to be working it's way up. Also rss seems to be pretty much climbing continuously. Anybody come across something like this. Seems like most memory leak tools focus in heap snapshots. How do I get into the rss to see what's going on in there?